# django admin export fields to pdf

Tags: django, pdf, export, admin

Does anyone know a Django application which can export (from the admin part) arbitrary entries from a table to pdf? Now the django-import-export application from Bojan Mihelac comes very close and works perfectly for xls, csv, json, asf., but not for pdf...

Answer (score 0):

You could use reportlab as described [here](http://www.puyb.net/download/djangobook/res.pdf) on page 134.